# Email Notification for SharePoint list when minimum amount of entries have been reached

Tags: workflow

How would I create an email notification for a SharePoint list when a minimum amount of entries have been reached?

For example, I have a basic list of 20 name entries, when that list reaches 15 names I need an auto-generated email to be sent out telling me that the name list has reached 15 names and I need to add more names

Comment: What version of SharePoint?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm working with SP2013 and SPDesigner 2013.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a SharePoint Designer Workflow on which will start on item added.
2. Look for the Item Id, if its equal to or greater than 15, send email notification else end the workflow.

Note: This is tentative method applicable to SharePoint 2010 because if you delete any items in a SharePoint list the Item Id is still incremental.

The best way would be count the item in the list which I am not sure if you can do it with SP Designer 2010 workflow.

Comment: Yes, the method above does not work with SP2013, since the Item ID does not re-numerate correctly.

Answer (score 0):

2013 workflows have a loop step. So you would create a variable to count your loops, and another to count your item. Then inside your loop activity, check for item with `ID=1`. If it exists, add to your count. Check for `ID=2`, etc... Stop once you hit the ID of the current item or hit count of 15. Go to email step.

Comment: http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2012/10/24/create-sharepoint-2013-workflow-loop-by-using-sharepoint-2013-designer-preview-aspx-2/

Answer (score 0):

You can make a REST API call to get the number of total items in your list. One of the sites I found explaining how to do this is [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/looping-through-list-items-in-sharepoint-2013)

You actually need to implement only the first 5 actions of this complicated looking workflow (up to the point where you get count). Then you can compare count to your limit and send an e-mail if necessary.

Obviously this workflow needs to be running periodically so perhaps a Pause for 4 hours action as the final action and loop back to Stage 1 again so it runs every 4 hours.